# Class as a delegate placeholder for a struct

Tags: swift

I have a simple struct where I use NSURLSession to get the data from the web. I would like to extend it to provide progress of downloading. I cannot use struct as a NSURLSession delegate because it needs to be a NSObject so I have created simple class where I pass to NSURLSession delegate. This is short version of my code:

```
struct Resource {

    private var progressDelegate: ProgressSessionDelegate?
    private var session: NSURLSession!

    init() {

        self.progressDelegate = ProgressSessionDelegate()
        let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self.progressDelegate!, delegateQueue: nil)
    }

    func loadAsynchronous(callback: A? -> ()) {
        session.dataTaskWithURL(resourceURL) {
            data, response, error in
            let json = data.flatMap {
                try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData($0, options: NSJSONReadingOptions())
            }
            callback(mycalback)
            }.resume()
    }
}
```

and thats my cass which should handle the delegate methods:

```
class ProgressSessionDelegate: NSObject, NSURLSessionDelegate, NSURLSessionDataDelegate {

    var expectedContentLength = 0
    var currentLength = 0

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse, completionHandler: (NSURLSessionResponseDisposition) -> Void) {

        expectedContentLength = Int(response.expectedContentLength)
        print("0: \(expectedContentLength)")
        completionHandler(NSURLSessionResponseDisposition.Allow)
    }

    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask, didReceiveData data: NSData) {

        self.currentLength += data.length
        let percentageDownloaded = Float(self.currentLength) / Float(self.expectedContentLength)
        print("1: \(percentageDownloaded)")
    }
    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: NSError?) {
        print("Downloaded")
    }
}
```

The problem is that the delegate methods are not called.

When I move the code from Resource and ProgressSessionDelegate struct to my ViewController and set up ViewController as a NSURLSession delegate all is working fine. I think the problem is in a way how the class is stored is struct.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Its probably because your progressDelegate is private, NSObject is old stuff and not used to tags like private

Comment: @Arbitur I remove the private keyword but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Show us where you initialize the struct, and check if the struct is not lost. Because it is a struct it will not get allocated in heap, it will go to stack.

Comment: @Arbitur In my ViewController I have property var res: Resource and I initialise it in viewDIdLoad so that is not the case. My view controller is the only one I have so it keeps my struct alive as long as it's active.

Comment: add deinit method in ProgressSessionDelegate and see it gets deallocated, if that doesnt happen, then I dont know what could be the problem.

Comment: I added but it's not deallocated. The class it's initialised but never deallocated. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What about setting the delegateQueue to: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()?

Comment: @squarehippo10 that's a queue on which one the delegate methods are called. I only print the values to the console so the queue doesn't matter.